# How to create URDF file from 3D model (OBJ)

Tags: python, animation, game-physics, maya, bulletphysics

I have .obj file for 3d model and I wanted to load it in pybullet. I see there is a loadURDF api which loads the URDF files. So in order to load obj I guess first we need to export obj to URDF.

Is there a way to do that either using Maya with bullet plug in or any other methods.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

At URDF file you can directly use .obj as mesh. Here is an example
https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/blob/master/data/teddy_vhacd.urdf

Comment: Figured it out. Thank you for your response.